# Can energy bend space?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, curvature, mass-energy

I know mass bends the space around it and I also remember matter can be converted into energy and vice versa, so my question is: can energy interact with space in a similar fashion as matter does?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How energy curves spacetime?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70993/)

Comment: I think there are many other duplicates as well. This was just the first one I found in a [search of this site](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=energy+curve+spacetime).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the source of the gravitational field in general relativity is the [stress-energy tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) The $00$ component is the total energy density

Comment: Can you provide a layman explanation of what is stress energy tensor, I tried searching however they are mostly written in jargon thanks.

Comment: Since the word tensor in tbe name already takes it out of the layman realm, I don't think so. But someone may have a good heuristic.

Comment: @user6760: The stress-energy tensor is simply a set of 16 numbers that describe the various forms of energies in space, whether it be in the form of matter, flux of matter, shear stress, pressure, etc. All give rise to a change in the space(time) in which this energy is distributed.